# How can i have focus on label tag using .focus () in javascript

Tags: javascript, focus, label

I am having Html in which i need focus on label tag when input is clicked

```
<li class="princee"  data-category="connectivity">
 <label class="pack-switch" tabindex="0">
 <input class="airplaneMode-input uninit lambas"  type="checkbox">
 <span id="menuItem-airplaneMode" class="menu-item" data-icon="airplane" data-l10n-id="airplaneMode"></span>
 </label>
 </li>
```

Answer (score 1):

Try the following code

```
<li class="princee"  data-category="connectivity">
<label class="pack-switch" tabindex="0" id="cc" contenteditable>Focus Here</label>
<input class="airplaneMode-input uninit lambas"  type="checkbox"  onchange="scriptmethod()">
<span id="menuItem-airplaneMode" class="menu-item" data-icon="airplane" data-l10n-id="airplaneMode"></span>
```

Script

```
function scriptmethod()
{   
 document.getElementById("cc").focus();
}
```

Comment: Hi Vinoth .Sorry but this code didn't worked because .focus() didn't bring focus on label tag

Comment: No @Vinoth Still Not working .focus() didn't brings focus on label and i am not able to change my html i only have to do it using javascript or css(input tag is inside label).

Comment: actually while u click the check box it focus on the label ly. but we cannot see that .if u write some bootstrap class means u can reorganize it focusing label.

Comment: for example instant of label u are using textbox means  the cursor will focus  there .but if label means cursor wont show there...i think so

Comment: Actually Vinoth I need focus on label tag itself  .

Comment: Now try this it il focus your label..@ user3454799

Comment: To clarify, the label's attribute `tabindex` converts the label from a non-focusable into a focusable element, at least with Firefox 112. Behavior of [focus()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLElement/focus) may have changed in 2019.